# Can spring JMX export the same bean instance under two different bean names?

Tags: java, spring, jmx

In Spring 3.1 I am trying to export the same bean via JMX under two different bean names with two different interfaces.

Below is some example spring xml configuration showing what I am trying to do:

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
<property name="beans">
  <map>
    <entry key="internal:name=internalName" value-ref="myBean"/>
    <entry key="external:name=externalName" value-ref="myBean"/>
  </map>
</property>
<property name="assembler">
  <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.InterfaceBasedMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="interfaceMappings">
      <props>
        <prop key="internal:name=internalName">InternalMXBean</prop>
        <prop key="external:name=externalName">ExternalMXBean</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>
```

myBean implements both of the interfaces I am trying to expose via JMX.

However, when I start my application I get the exception

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: MXBean already registered with name internal:name=internalName
```

Is there any way of registering the same bean instance under two different mbean names exposing a different interface?

Comment: Do you really want to do that? Won't this cause confusion? If your class is implementing two interfaces, maybe you should split it into two classes. You can create another class that integrates both instances, so you don't need to change other code.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is to have the same bean expose one MXBean for customer/external usage and one MXBean for internal/support usage. The InternalMXBean interface extends the ExternalMXBean interface. I can't split the bean class up and don't really want to write an extra code just to handle the different interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can you register the same MBean with more than one name?](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2005/07/16/can-you-register-same-mbean-more-one-name) indicates that you can register the same MBean under different names but provides some reasoning as to why this could be a bad idea.

In my specific case I am using MXBeans. The same MXBean cannot be registered under different object names as this would conflict with support for inter-MXBean references.

Comment: The link does not work anymore. I suppose, that article can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/emcmanus/2005/07/16/can-you-register-same-mbean-more-one-name) now.